# Difference between mean(c(1,2,21)) and mean(1,2,21)

Tags: r

What's the difference between these two?

```
mean(c(1,2,21))
```

and

```
mean(1,2,21)
```

The answers are different, but what's the meaning of each one?

Comment: This is a very basic R question. Basically, in the first case you are taking the mean of a vector of three elements; in the other case, you are taking the mean of 1 and providing some useless informations to the arguments of the `mean` function. Look at `?mean`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mean(c(1,2,21))
#[1] 8
```

This passes a vector of three elements to the `mean` function and the mean value of these three elements is calculated.

```
mean(1,2,21)
#[1] 1
```

This passes `1` as the first argument, `2` as the second argument and `21` as the third argument to the `mean` function. `mean` passes these arguments to `mean.default`. In `help("mean.default")` you can find the arguments of this function:

1. The object you want the mean for.
2. the fraction (0 to 0.5) of observations to be trimmed from each end of x before the mean is computed. Values of trim outside that range are taken as the nearest endpoint.
3. a logical value indicating whether NA values should be stripped before the computation proceeds. (Since you pass a numeric value, it is coerced to logical automatically).

So you calculate this:

```
mean.default(1, 0.5, TRUE)
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `mean(c(1,2,21))` R is taking the mean out of the vector consisting of 1,2 and 21, in the second case, when using `mean(1,2,21)`, is equivalent to `mean(1, trim=2, na.rm=21)` and R is taking the mean out one single number, 1, and you are passing value 2 to `trim` which controls for the fraction (0 to 0.5) of observations to be trimmed from each end of the vector before the mean is computed, and also you are giving value `21` to `na.rm` argument, which should be `TRUE` or `FALSE`, as you can see 2 and 21 without `c` are completely useless here.