# Why doesn't the mean() function work for two numbers?

Tags: r, function, average, mean

I'd like to have some help with the use of `mean()` function.

I have tried calculating the mean of two numbers obtained by the sum of their vectors, but the `mean()`function just released the first of the two instead of actually calculating the mean. Here is the bit of code as an example:

```
a <- c(1,2,3)
b <- c(4,5,6)
sum_a <- sum(a)
sum_b <- sum(b)
mean(sum_a,sum_b)
```

> [1] 6

```
(sum_a+sum_b)/2
```

> [1] 10.5

Comment: Hello, you can read the reason in the help pages (`?mean`), you need to do `mean(c(sum_a, sum_b))`

Comment: See also [Difference between mean(c(1,2,21)) and mean(1,2,21)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22864363/difference-between-meanc1-2-21-and-mean1-2-21)